# Jquery Dropdown Menu: Menu lays BELOW div (can't 'mouse on top')

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, overlapping

I'm using drop down menu with structure such as below, with combination of CSS and jQuery to hide/display the Sub Items.

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Folder 0</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

My divs are placed like a table, this way:
MX
MX
MX
So, imagine there's two columns and three rows.. 
where each sections are div elements,
M->is the div where I put my the dropdown menu in,and
X->other divs

The problem that I'm having right now is that when the menu is clicked and submenus shows up, I can't select the submenu that overlaps the div in the bottom, it seem like it's below the div and I can't select it, 'mouse-over' it etc

Can someone help me with this isssue? So that I can have all my menus working perfectly

Comment: I'm having a rough time imagining the rest of the code...do you think you could add some more code examples detailing the `MX` concept a bit better?

Comment: Would need you to either show an example of the problem or a bit more explanation on what is happening such as is the submenu is being placed behind the dropdown menu?

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle for us to have a look at? You'll get more help that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you really insert your Menu behind your div assign larger z-index to your menu, and if not, If you use "display:--> none or hidden" in your css for LIs, you could use live for your mouseover to find your menu.
http://api.jquery.com/live/
have good time!

Comment: can you send me your code? if you can post here, if not send to my mail. find from my profile.